# Get DuplicateRule action from API

Tags: apex, duplicate-management, datacloud

The out of box Datacloud Apex classes gives lots of detailed info about why duplicates have occurred.  One such item is the developer name of the executed duplicate rule that returned duplicate records.  So far so good.  But when we look at the fields available for the DuplicateRule object, there is no field which shows the Action on Create, or the Action on Edit.

Now in our application, we are using the Datacloud Apex classes to enable us to see if DML operations fail because of Duplicate Rules.  What we are trying to see is what the Action on Create/Edit was for the rule which was executed and prevented the DML from succceeding.  we want to have different logic based on whether the Action is either Block or Allow.  So is there a way in Apex to get the Action on Create/Edit from the DuplicateRule?

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that there is actually a method on the Datacloud.DuplicateResult class called isAllowSave which gives me the info I need, and that I don't need to get the info from the DuplicateRule.